# Strings in C that finds vowels count

Tags: c, string

I need to take 'n' number of strings as input to find which string is having more vowels.(taking  n strings) .Tried arrays of strings but failed. Any help !

Comment: Show the code that you tried. It's not a problem that it failed now.

Comment: `Tried arrays of strings but failed.` Please show what you have tried?

Comment: I need many things, but generally I dont ask for it without trying to get it myself.

Comment: Where are the strings? `CLI`? Buffer? File? Get a pointer to a string and walk down it char_by_char testing if `aeiou` until you get to the null-pointer, then go to the next string....

Comment: It's too good to do homework ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

The moment that a problem involves "n inputs" without a clear indicator of the maximum number, you should ask yourself two things:

1) Do I need to keep the entire list to perform the task?

2) If I need to keep the entire list, what performance limitations do I have?

In the example you've given, it doesn't sound like you need to keep the entire list to perform the task -- Nobody is asking you to display the entire list at any point, only to track the string with the most vowels by the end of the list.

That sounds like you should have two strings -- the one you are evaluating and the one that is your current highest.

The pseudocode for what you're trying to do sounds like this:

```
highest_vowels = -1
while there are still more strings to evaluate
{
    eval_string = next string to evaluate
    eval_vowels = number of vowels in eval_string
    if eval_vowels > highest_vowels
    {
       highest_string = eval_string
       highest_vowels = eval_vowels
    }
}
if highest_vowels == -1
{
    Print "There were no strings to evaluate"
}
else
{
    Print "The string with the most vowels was: " + highest_string
}
```

In this example you are not keeping track of every string that you evaluated. You are only ever keeping track of two strings: the current one being evaluated and the one currently recognized as the "highest" in terms of vowels. It doesn't matter if I am given one string or one million strings, my code will eventually find the one with the highest.

If we had been asked to keep track of the entire list for the process, while this complicates things, there are more advanced data structures than a list that are excellent for this. One example of such a data structure is a linked list. Understand that deciding between these data structures is largely a matter of deciding what limitations on our performance we can afford for the given task (Question 2).

Comment: Nice explanation, and I like that you explained what to do without handing over a complete solution.  +1.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
   int v_count=0,i,j;
   int max=0,max_string;
   char a[5][14]={"asdfij","nbioeolk","qwerjiu","asdfvcx","oiajkmnb"};
   for (j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
      v_count=0;// reset the counter in each iteration
      for(i=0;a[j][i]!='\0';++i)
       {
         //checking whether the letter is vowel or not in each string
         if(a[j][i]=='a' || a[j][i]=='e' || a[j][i]=='i' || a[j][i]=='o' || a[j][i]=='u' || a[j][i]=='A' || a[j][i]=='E' || a[j][i]=='I' || a[j][i]=='O' || a[j][i]=='U')
         ++v_count;   // increment the count if a vowel is present
       }
      if(v_count>max)
      {
       max_string=j;
       max=v_count;
      }
   }
   printf("%d,%s",max,a[max_string]);
}
```

**Notes:**

- You can improve the code by accepting 'n' input from the user

Comment: thanks.... it gives the count of highest vowels. But I need at which string encountered the highest vowel count.

Comment: If the answer is acceptable then show your support

Comment: @user3479901: see the updates

Comment: +1, but it'd be less fragile to use `const char* a[5] = ...` so you don't have to worry about length (i.e. if 14 becomes too small after an edit), and it should be `j < 5` or - better yet - `j < sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`.  just a suggestion: `strchr("aeiouAEIOU", a[j][i])` would be a more concise/readable test, if no strings have any vowels `a[max_string]` has undefined behaviour as `max_string` is unintialised, and it's best to append a `'\n'` - many shells will issue cursor placement instructions to overwrite the current line without checking the last program run had advanced the cursor.

Comment: superb .. thanks once again LOsunG

Comment: @ user3479901: accept the answer to denote its true